# JavaScript: Convert Hindi numeral to Arabic one on fly while typing in an input text

Tags: javascript, input, character-encoding

I am trying to create a JavaScript code to convert Hindi Numerals [١،٢،٣،٤،٥،٦]  to Arabic numeral [1,2,3,4,5,6] on fly. This means I am trying to convert numbers so that it is easier for programming languages. The problem what ever I do I can not get rid of the last pressed digit in Hindi so when I press ٢ I can change it to 2 but what happens I will get ٢2 at the same time. Would you please let me know how to implement that so that if the user inputs ١٠٠ in the textbox it will convert it to 100 on just like he is actually typeing 100 with the keyboard.

After too many attempts I have stopped here Which is not doing what I want

```js
var digits = [1633, 1634, 1635, 1636, 1637, 1638, 1639, 1640, 1641, 1632];
var d = "";
function convert(event) {
    var x = event.which || event.charCode;
    var i = document.getElementById("barCode").value.length;

    if(digits.includes(x)){
        document.getElementById("barCode").value = String.fromCharCode(x - 1584);
    }

    console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<p>A function is triggered when the user is pressing a key in the input field.</p>

<input type="text" id="barCode" keyup="convert(event)">
```

Comment: Show us the code you're working with. I can't fix code I can't see. I'm decent at this but I'm not god mode.

Comment: @gforce301 Thanks for your reply I have updated the question to have the latest code

Comment: Nope. I still don't see any code. Please put the code in the post **on this site**.

Comment: @gforce301 I hope this code will clarify the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but then the input should be an array and you can use `split` for this. At the end we return it to a string again with `join`:

```js
var hindi = ['٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'];
var arabic = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function translate(input) {
   var array = input.split('');
   array.map(function(value, i, array) {
     if (hindi.indexOf(array[i]) >= 0) {
       array[i] = arabic[hindi.indexOf(array[i])];
     }
   });
   return array.join('');
}

// Example of input
console.log(translate('١٠٠')); // 100
```

Now you can use your convert function to call it:

```js
var hindi = ['٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'];
var arabic = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

function translate(input) {
   var array = input.split('');
   array.map(function(value, i, array) {
     if (hindi.indexOf(array[i]) >= 0) {
      array[i] = arabic[hindi.indexOf(array[i])];
     }
   });
   return array.join('');
}

function convert(event) {
    var barcode = document.getElementById("barCode");
    var val = barcode.value;
    barcode.value = translate(val);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="barCode" onkeyup="convert(event)">
```

Also, you can see it working in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/jeprubio/pen/VwYgMGX).

Comment: But how to do that on fly. I mean while the user is typing the numbers not later

Comment: I've changed it to a function, you can use `translate()` passing the input anywhere you need it. Note you still have to enter from 7 to 9 in the hindi and arabic arrays for it to work.

Comment: The issue is when I use anything with onkey events I will not get the required result because of it will attach the last pressed key to the end of textfeild value

Comment: you can get the textfield value if you wish, check the convert funtion I've added to the answer

Comment: Grab his code and copy to your answer. You can leave your original. Use your convert function in the copy of his code and you have an answer I'll upvote.

Comment: @gforce301 I've updated the answer with all the code for the onkeyup of the input text. You can test it now

Comment: very nice answer.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. but the problem with this method is a bit strange. as the last entred digit will remain untill next one is added then it converts to the Arabic digit. just shown here how it behaves [Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/aZjVUbY.gifv)

Comment: I think I've found this remaining numbers, I've added them. Check the below code snippet now or the updated codepen. If it stops translating the numbers at some point chech if you have a javascript error in the console